# Connect to Cloud SQL from Google Functions using Private IP

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL Instance and plan to access it from a Google Function using NodeJS. The code is as given in the documentation

```
// mysql
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connectionName = process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME || 'project:region:sql-instance';
const dbUser = process.env.SQL_USER || 'root';
const dbPassword = process.env.SQL_PASSWORD || 'password';
const dbName = process.env.SQL_NAME || 'database';

const mysqlConfig = {
  connectionLimit: 1,
  user: dbUser,
  password: dbPassword,
  database: dbName,
};
//if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;
//}

// Connection pools reuse connections between invocations,
// and handle dropped or expired connections automatically.
let mysqlPool;

function searchDB() {
  if (!mysqlPool) {
    mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
    console.log(mysqlPool);
  }
  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    mysqlPool.query('SELECT * FROM table', (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('error in retrieving data:', err);
        resolve(''); // sending blank response
      } else {
        console.log('success in getting data', JSON.stringify(results));
        resolve(JSON.stringify(results));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I am able to access the database when I set it with public IP. However, when I set it to Private IP I get an `ECON refused` error.

Question is: what changes I need to do in the Google Functions code to access it using Private IP? Thanks

Comment: My initial feeling is that the private IP is seen as going to a non-Google owned network, which is disallowed for projects on a free plan. You might want to try if upgrading to a paid plan works (there is still a free quota on the Blaze plan). If that solves it, I'm actually not sure if this is working as intended, so you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting for that.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen. Will check out as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private IP's are only accessible by other services on the same [Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/). Since your Function runs on a managed network, it is currently outside your VPC and doesn't have access to your Cloud SQL instance.

Google Cloud Functions does provide a unix domain socket to interface with Cloud SQL instances, but it requires the instance to have a public IP. As long as `mysqlConfig.socketPath = cloudsql/${connectionName};` uses the correct connection name (in the format `project:region:instance`), you should be able to connect. If you are using a cross product or cross regional setup, there are more instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#setting_up_cloud_sql).

**Update:** Since originally posting this, a new product called the [Serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) has become available that can allow access to a VPC resource. You can follow the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc#configuring) to configure it, and then connect to the instance with it's private IP (instead of the `/cloudsql/` socket mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks @kurtisvg for the response. I tried reading up but since the socketPath in the above code has been set using `$connectionName` am I not passing the instance name viz. `project:region:sql-instance` ... of course replace by the actual project, region and sql-instance? Or am I misunderstanding your solution? Thanks

Comment: Yes, update `$connectionName` with the correct instance connection name. You can copy it from the details page for your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: @kurtisvg could you elaborate on your anwser or give an example on what would you suggest to put there, because from how I understand it RmR is doing exactly what you suggest in the first place, but it doesn't work if you switch to private IP from public IP on the cloud SQL instance connection configuration.

Comment: @alobodzk - I've updated it to better reflect the current state of things :)